# In what cases does imul write to edx?

Tags: assembly, x86

It was my understanding that the output of `imul` is `edx:eax`, meaning `imul` should overwrite `edx`.  However, I just ran into an issue where

```
imul eax, 10
```

is not clearing `edx`.

Under what circumstances does `imul` write to `edx`?  I checked multiple x86 documentation sites, and they all seem to have conflicting information.

Comment: The only thing you should check is the official intel instruction set reference. It doesn't conflict and is authoritative. TL;DR: only the single operand version uses `edx`:`eax` implicitly.

Comment: If not using the Intel reference, the 3rd party reference at http://x86.renejeschke.de/ . Is also very good for the 386. It too shows that only the single operand form writes to EDX:EAX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the single-operand form of the `imul` instruction writes to `EDX:EAX` pair. The two and three-operand forms truncate the result.

If you wrote

```
mov ecx, 10
imul ecx
```

then `EAX` would be multiplied by 10, and `EDX` would be overwritten.